# Extracting data from JSON depending on other parameters

Tags: python, json

What are the options for extracting value from JSON depending on other parameters (using python)? For example, JSON:

```
"list": [
    {
        "name": "value",
        "id": "123456789"
    },
    {
        "name": "needed-value",
        "id": "987654321"
    }
]
```

When using `json_name["list"][0]["id"]` it obviously returns `123456789`. Is there a way to indicate `"name"` value `"needed-value"` so i could get `987654321` in return?

Comment: `json_name["list"][1]["id"]` would return this, no?

Comment: You have to iterate the list of dict and match with the key 'name` with the value you provide and return the corresponding id value

Comment: @d_kennetz Yes, it works if we put it that way. In my case, I need a way to specifically indicate a "name" value after which "id" is returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```
import json as j

s = '''
{
"list": [
    {
        "name": "value",
        "id": "123456789"
    },
    {
        "name": "needed-value",
        "id": "987654321"
    }
]
}
'''

js = j.loads(s)
print [x["id"] for x in js["list"] if x["name"] == "needed-value"]
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle this is to refactor the json as a single dictionary. Since "name" and "id" are redundant you can make the dictionary with the *value* from "name" as the key and the value from "id" as the value.

```
import json

j = '''{
    "list":[
        {
            "name": "value",
            "id": "123456789"
        },{
            "name": "needed-value",
            "id": "987654321"
        }
    ]
}'''


jlist = json.loads(j)['list']
d = {jd['name']: jd['id'] for jd in jlist}
print(d) ##{'value': '123456789', 'needed-value': '987654321'}
```

Now you can iterate the items like you normally would from a dictionary.

```
for k, v in d.items():
    print(k, v)
# value 123456789
# needed-value 987654321
```

And since the names are now hashed, you can check membership more efficiently than continually querying the list.

```
assert 'needed-value' in d
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jsn = {
    "list": [
        {
            "name": "value",
            "id": "123456789"
        },
        {
            "name": "needed-value",
            "id": "987654321"
        }
    ]
}

def get_id(list, name):
    for el in list:
        if el['name'] == name:
            yield el['id']

print(list(get_id(jsn['list'], 'needed-value')))
```

Answer (score -1):

Python innately treats JSON as a list of dictionaries. With this in mind, you can call the index of the list you need to be returned since you know it's location in the list (and child dictionary).

In your case, I would use `list[1]["id"]`

If, however, you don't know where the position of your needed value is within the list, the you can run an old fashioned for loop this way:

```
for user in list:
    if user["name"] == "needed_value":
        return user["id"]
```

This is assuming you only have one unique needed_value in your list.